# Load more MYSQL results on button click PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a table of data, and I only want the first 5 entries to load, with a button at the bottom will load the entries 6 to 11. I've tried a few variations on adding a button but it's not showing the correct entries, the button at the moment will just show the same entries again. Here is the section of code;

```
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM memo Where uid = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $uid2);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $note, $uid3);
    }
    $output   = array();
    $out_id   = array();
    $out_note = array();
    $i = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        ("SELECT * FROM memo Where uid = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6, 11");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $uid2);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $note, $uid3);
    }
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $out_note[$i] = $note;
        echo $out_note[$i] . " <br>";
        $i++;
    }
    $output = array(
        $out_note,
        $out_id
    );
    rsort($output);
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about pagination.  Limit is equal to fetch records from x record and fetch y number of records.  The records from x to y become a page.  For example page number 1 will have records from 0 to 5 and page number 2 will have records from 6 to 6+5.  So you have number of records per page as a variable, start record as variable and page number as a variable.  Based on that you can set the logic.

Comment: Pagination isn't really what I'm aiming for in this case, ideally, I want it to be an infinite scroll, something like a Facebook timeline.

Comment: That's still pagination, just loading more results when you reach the bottom instead of when you click something. There's a bunch of ways to do that, probably best to use ajax if you want to load just the next set each time. Not exactly the same thing, this answer is kinda similar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501162/1318813