# How to Lazy load datatable with client sided processing?

Tags: django-rest-framework, datatables

I have a table with 3500 entries and foreign keys.

I'm using client-sided processing datatables with: django-rest-framework and Ajax.

It takes up to 10 seconds to load.

Is there a way to show the first 10 entries (first page results) -  for the user not to think that my website is broken, because it's taking too long - while the rest of the entries loads in the background?

Also looking for optimizations for the load speed.
Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
models.py

```
class Bibrest51(models.Model):
    cadastro_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    autor = models.CharField(db_column='Autor', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tema = models.ForeignKey('BibTema', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    tipo = models.ForeignKey('Tipo', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bibrest51'
    @property
    def bib_tipo_nome(self):
        return self.tipo.tipo_nome

class BibTema(models.Model):
    tema_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tema_nome = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tema'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tema_nome
```

serializers.py

```
class TemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BibTema
        fields = '__all__'   
        depth = 1

class TipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tipo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth= 1

class BibSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    temas = TemaSerializer(read_only=True)
    tipos = TipoSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Bibrest51
        fields = (
            'autor', 'ano', 'titulo', 'referencia','tipos','temas'
            
        )
```

Comment: You may (or may not) see some improvement by using [deferRender](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender), with a page size of 10 rows (as an example). Otherwise, using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) may be needed.

Comment: I have never used it, but the [Scroller](https://datatables.net/blog/2011-06-11) add-on may also be worth a look.

Comment: @andrewjames I tried the bdeferrender option with no change in speed, i will take a look at the pluguin, thank you

Comment: I talked with my client and Scroller is NOT an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimization you can use:

- [Nested relationship serializing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)
- [Pagination System](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)
- [Caching output](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)
- Using [select-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

> Is there a way to show the first 10 entries (first page results) - for the user not to think that my website is broken, because it's taking too long - while the rest of the entries loads in the background?

You can implement this with pagination. Request the first 10 records and if the total number of records is more than 10, then request the rest in the background

### UPDATED

For serializer try this:

```
class TemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BibTema
        fields = '__all__'   
        # depth= 1   # delete string

class TipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tipo
        fields = '__all__'
        # depth= 1   # delete string

class BibSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    temas = TemaSerializer(read_only=True, sourse='tema')
    tipos = TipoSerializer(read_only=True, sourse='tipo')
    class Meta:
        model = Bibrest51
        # There are fewer fields in the code you provided, 
        # so I rely on you for this.
        fields = (
            'autor', 'ano', 'titulo', 'referencia','tipos','temas'
            
        )
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you please give pointers of the js code i need to use to:
request the first 10 records then load the rest in the background?

Comment: I don't understand how you see the result. Why not implement regular pagination or scrolling pagination?

Comment: i use pagination(10 items), still the data is loaded upfront, scrolling is not an option according to my client

Comment: I tried using nested serialization without success.

Comment: You have not specified how you see the result. Try to read the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475235/creating-ajax-pagination/27501162). And what you fail with nested serialization. Can you provide the code for the models and serializers?

Comment: Added the code , i will take a look at that thanks

Comment: Answer updated. Try these serializer changes

Comment: Thank you again for your time, the nested serialization is now working,i saw a 25% improvement in the loading time! Now i'm  working on the pagination

Comment: use `queryset = Bibrest51.objects.select_related('tema', 'tipo')` to minimize database queries

Comment: and if you use django-debug-toolbar, then tracking the caching system greatly slows down the formation of the template and, as a result, the page load. This problem has appeared since version 3

Comment: @ AlexElizard setting the queryset minimized time to 2 seconds! resolved.